# requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects

Tags: python, requests

Я парсю этот [портал](http://vesti.kz/).Заголовок,дату и контент новости.И при парсинге использую python 3.7 библиотеку `BS4`

И вот при парсинге этого [портала](http://vesti.kz/) у меня выходит такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 124, in <module>
    call_all_func(resources)
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 104, in call_all_func
    item_page = get_html(resource_link)
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 14, in get_html
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 668, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 668, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 165, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded %s redirects.' % self.max_redirects, response=resp)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Вот строчка кода `request` запроса

> ```
> def get_html(url):
>     r = requests.get(url)
>     return r.text
> ```

Пробовал делать так

> ```
> def get_html(url):
>     r = requests.get(url,allow_redirects=True)
>     return r.text
> ```

Но это мне не помогло.

Я из ошибки понял только то,что превышено 30 перенаправлений.Как устранить эту ошибку ?

Comment: У меня не получилось воспроизвести ошибку, все работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел в чем была причина:Циклические редиректы. То есть странница ссылается на саму себя, и requests при попытке дойти до итоговой страницы превышает лимит запросов. Решение проблемы - игнорировать ошибку. Перехватывать ее.

> ```
> # < Получаем html код.
> def get_html(url):
>     try:
>         r = requests.get(url)
>         return r.text
>     except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
>         pass
> ```